# Procedure for generating .d.ts from js file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to convert my JavaScript file to TypeScript definition (.d.ts).

I am unable to find a tool that does this automatically OR a well defined procedure for converting .js to .ts or .d.ts file.

Could anyone please share the proper procedure for getting .d.ts file for .js  file?

Thanks,
Saravanan

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately it is still a manual process. You can however convert your `.js` file to a TypeScript `.ts` file and then the typescript compiler can generate a `.d.ts` for you using the `-d` compiler flag. e.g. the following will give you a `foo.d.ts` and a `foo.js`

```
tsc -d foo.ts --out foo.js
```

There is disucssion of various tools that you can investigate but none of them are 100% at the moment : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/2103#issuecomment-41899391

Answer (score 0):

try the code below. In fact , the following code does not generate .d.ts files, but it generates the tree can write .d.ts file for you to provide a reference , which gives most of the objects of the type of property and function parameters The number of

```
var Helper = (function () {
    function Helper() {
    }
    Helper.MAX_DUMP_DEPTH = 10;
    Helper.dumpObj = function (obj, name, indent, depth) {
        if (depth > Helper.MAX_DUMP_DEPTH) {
            return indent + name + typeof(obj) +": <Maximum Depth Reached>\n";
        }
        var pre = '';
        pre = (name + '').substr(0, 1);
        if (pre == '_' || pre == '-') {
            return '';
        }
        if (typeof obj == "object") {
            var child = null;
            var output = indent + name + typeof(obj)+"\n";
            indent += "\t";
            for (var item in obj) {
                pre = (item + '').substr(0, 1);
                if (pre == '_' || pre == '-') {
                    continue;
                }
                var temp = obj[item] + '';
                try {
                    child = obj[item];
                }
                catch (e) {
                    child = "<Unable to Evaluate>";
                }
                if (typeof child == "object") {
                    output += Helper.dumpObj(child, item, indent, depth + 1);
                }
                else {
                    output += indent + item + ": " + temp.substr(0, 1 + temp.indexOf(')'))+ typeof(child) + "\n";
                }
            }
            return output;
        }
        else {
            return obj;
        }
    };
    return Helper;
})();


Helper.dumpObj(yourobj,"yourobj","    ",0)
```

Comment: And exactly how does one run this? gulpfile? right at the nodejs console?