# How create typescript d.ts from js

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am beginner in typescript and could someone give me a hint: How will look like d.ts file from js library https://github.com/bettiolo/oauth-signature-js/blob/master/src/app/oauth-signature.js

Comment: I described the process in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33044217/typescript-definition-file-for-spservices/33064546#33064546

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Procedure for generating .d.ts from js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23379198/procedure-for-generating-d-ts-from-js-file)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to automatically create `d.ts` files.
You should write it.
Although you can look into [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/)
library, there are many typings for popular libraries.